# Cannot create event session - SQL Server extended events

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, logging, extended-events

I'm trying to automate extended events logger for a few SQL Servers. I have a template SQL script which should create event session.

```
CREATE EVENT SESSION [sql-queries-test] ON SERVER
    ADD EVENT sqlserver.sql_batch_completed(SET collect_batch_text=(1)
        ACTION(sqlserver.client_app_name,sqlserver.client_connection_id,sqlserver.client_hostname,sqlserver.database_id,sqlserver.database_name,sqlserver.nt_username,sqlserver.server_instance_name,sqlserver.server_principal_name,sqlserver.server_principal_sid,sqlserver.session_nt_username,sqlserver.sql_text,sqlserver.tsql_stack,sqlserver.username)
        WHERE ([sqlserver].[like_i_sql_unicode_string]([sqlserver].[sql_text],N'%SELECT%') OR [sqlserver].[like_i_sql_unicode_string]([sqlserver].[sql_text],N'%UPDATE%') OR [sqlserver].[like_i_sql_unicode_string]([sqlserver].[sql_text],N'%DELETE%') OR [sqlserver].[like_i_sql_unicode_string]([sqlserver].[sql_text],N'%INSERT%') OR [sqlserver].[like_i_sql_unicode_string]([sqlserver].[sql_text],N'%CREATE%') OR [sqlserver].[like_i_sql_unicode_string]([sqlserver].[sql_text],N'%ALTER%') AND [sqlserver].[database_name]<>N'master'))
    ADD TARGET package0.event_file(SET filename=N'D:\test\sql-queries-test.xel',max_rollover_files=(0))
    WITH (MAX_MEMORY=102400 KB,
    EVENT_RETENTION_MODE=ALLOW_SINGLE_EVENT_LOSS,MAX_DISPATCH_LATENCY=30 SECONDS,
    MAX_EVENT_SIZE=0 KB,
    MEMORY_PARTITION_MODE=NONE,
    TRACK_CAUSALITY=OFF,
    STARTUP_STATE=ON)
```

Unfortunately running this results in an error

> CREATE EVENT SESSION statement cannot be used inside a user transaction.

Accordingly to `fn_builtin_permissions` I have `ALTER ANY EVENT SESSION` permission, which is need :

> On SQL Server, requires the ALTER ANY EVENT SESSION permission. On SQL
> Database, requires the ALTER ANY DATABASE EVENT SESSION permission in
> the database.
> [[source]](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-event-session-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: How are you trying to deploy this script? From Python? Using pyodbc by chance?

Comment: I was trying using it in python with SQL alchemy engine.execute, 
But later I tried also MSSMS and it didn't work too.

Comment: I would expect it to work in SSMS and not in pyodbc. pyodbc has the autocommit=false/true setting that controls whether it automatically commits after each operation or whether you must call connection.commit manually, but the upshot is that everything it does is inside a transaction so wouldn't work for this type of operation. It should work inside SSMS, however.

Comment: I asked my colleague with admin on this server to run same script. It ran with no problem. 
After running 
SELECT * FROM fn_my_permissions(NULL, 'SERVER') where permission_name like '%EVENT%'
It seems that we had same 'event' permissions on server.